# Where does the H2 database get stored?

Tags: java, h2

I just started using H2 to learn SQL. I was wondering where H2 database values are stored. The main reason I'm trying to find this out is that I'd like to look at the values that I entered and see the general structure that the database takes. Currently I'm using the URL "10.53.87.49:8082" on Firefox but that doesn't show me new values entered via my main java class.

Comment: What connection URL did you use?  You could also take a look at [Where are the Database Files Stored?](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files)

Answer (score 4):

The answer will depend on you connection URL

From the [FAQs](http://www.h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files)

> Where are the Database Files Stored?
>
> When using database URLs like jdbc:h2:~/test, the database is stored
>   in the user directory. For Windows, this is usually C:\Documents and
>   Settings\ or C:\Users\. If the base directory is
>   not set (as in jdbc:h2:test), the database files are stored in the
>   directory where the application is started (the current working
>   directory). When using the H2 Console application from the start menu,
>   this is /bin. The base directory can be set in
>   the database URL. A fixed or relative path can be used. When using the
>   URL jdbc:h2:file:data/sample, the database is stored in the directory
>   data (relative to the current working directory). The directory is
>   created automatically if it does not yet exist. It is also possible to
>   use the fully qualified directory name (and for Windows, drive name).
>   Example: jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/test